# How to list all logged in users on the SharePoint portal?

Tags: sharepoint

I have this code to list all users on the SharePoint portal:

> using (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite mSite = new
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(GetCurrentSiteURL()))
>           {
>
> ```
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb rootWeb = mSite.RootWeb;
>         for (int i = 0; i < rootWeb.AllUsers.Count; i++)
>         {
>             int j = 0;
>             char[] anyOf = new char[] { '#', '+' };
>             rootWeb.AllUsers[i].
>
>             if (rootWeb.AllUsers[i].LoginName.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '#', '+' }) == -1)//if(!rootWeb.AllUsers[i].IsDomainGroup)   
>
>             {
>                 box1.Items.Insert(j, rootWeb.AllUsers[i].LoginName);
>                 j += 1;
>             }
>         }
> ```

**Is it possilbe to list only those users who are currently logged in?**

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint does not provide any means to figure out who is currently logged on. This is due to the fact, that SharePoint uses `HTTP` to transmit data. As `HTTP` is a stateless protocol, you don't know if a user is currently online, even if he/she just requested a site from your SiteCollection a few seconds ago.
If you want to achieve something like this, you would need to create a `WebPart` which tracks logged-on users and install it to your farm (if you can deploy a `Farm-Solution` to the GAC of the server). This won't work with `SandBoxed-Solutions` at all because of the restricted rights and API.
Besides, the `AllUsers`-property of `RootWeb` shows all the registered users, but you cannot gain any information on their online-Status.

Comment: I realy appreciate your help.  I spent entire day yesterday and today with no fuit to share. Thanks again.

Comment: I know how depressant it can get if you just can't advance with your research. I am glad I could help. Nevertheless, don't give up. If you don't work with `Sandboxed` Solutions, there is a way!!